# Centering Navigation ul li

Tags: css, centering, nav

I can't seem to get the main navigation bar to center align the li elements. I'm only having problems when the browser is under 768px. I've tried display: inline-block on the #nav ul and then text align to no avail. Here is the site:
[Website](http://bit.ly/1bw5qJC)

and here is the CSS in question:

```
/* Main Navigation */   
#topmenu {float: left; height: auto; text-align: center; margin: -10px auto -10px 10px; display: block; width: 96%;}
#nav {float: left; border-left: none; margin: 10px auto 0px; text-align: center;  display: block; width: 100%;}
#nav li {float: left; margin-right: auto; border-right: none; width: auto;}
#nav li a:link, #nav li a:active, #nav li a:visited {display: block;text-decoration: none; line-height: 20px; outline: medium none; font-size: 19px; letter-spacing: -0.05em; float: left;    padding: 6px 9px 8px; text-align: center; width: auto;}
span.descmenu {display: none;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply these properties/values

```
#nav {
    text-align: center; /*add*/
}
#nav li {
    display: inline-block; /*add*/
    text-align: left; /*add*/
    float: none; /*change left to none on max-width: 767px */
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. I made things too complicated.

Answer (score 1):

The `display:inline-block` and `text-align: center` technique does work here, but you need to make sure that on the smaller screen your ul (`#nav`) is not floated and doesn't have a width set.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  #nav {
    float: none; /* Changed from float: left*/
    border-left: none;
    margin: 10px auto 0px;
    /* text-align: center; NOT NEEDED */
    display: inline-block; /* Changed from display: block */
    /*width: 100%; Remove */
  }
}
```

Comment: Appreciate the help David. I did remove those unnecessary lines.

Answer (score 0):

This will center the sub heading in the navbar

```
#nav {
 text-align: center;
}
```

Having a look at the css it looks like a float:left or padding/margin might be overiding the li your wanting to style.